# Adding empty key, value pair to javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

How can I add empty (key,value) pair to an existing object.
suppose I have an object as

```js
var map = {
    "name": "x"
};
```

How can I get below output

```js
var map = {
    "name": "x",
    "": ""
};
```

I am looking for similar to push function in case of array.

Comment: what have you tried? why not simply `map[""] = "";`? Why should it be related to array's push? (I'm smelling an XY problem here, maybe details of why you want to do this could help)

Comment: I'm not sure for what reason you would ever do that, but it's just `map[""] = ""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the `[]` operator, like that :

```
var map = {
    "name": "x"
};

map[""] = "";
```